# Which photo managers feature publish services similar to Lightroom?

Tags: photo-management, digital-asset-management

Lightroom has a feature called publish services. There you can setup collections (published folders) of photos, which will be published to a folder with preset export settings. Changing a photo which is part of such a collection will update the exported photo at the next time that collection gets published.
Especially those collections can be set to include photos automatically (published smart folder). E.g. my collection Family includes all photos tagged Family and rated with three or more stars.

As there won't be any perpetual licenses for future Lightroom software nor longterm support of the recent Lightroom, I am looking for an alternative preferably with perpetual license and without the tendency of trying to cloud all the users work.

Are there any other photo managers with a feature similar to the described publish services?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this software has what you need, but I've been using Neofinder [[https://www.neofinder.de]](https://www.neofinder.de)now for a couple of years and have found it capable of handling all my DAM tasks. However it has no "processing" tool, so you will still need a standalone processor, I use Affinity Photo for this.

Comment: Seems like this will only work for Macs. I use Windows or Linux. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Then there is this software, http://abemeda.com/ it’s windows so I can’t vouch for it but it has some symbiotic connection to NeoFinder